# Unknown CMake command: "_Boost_UPDATE_WINDOWS_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_WITH_PREBUILT_PATHS"

Tags: boost, cmake

Environment:

- Windows 10
- CMake 3.12.4
- Boost 1.68.0 installed from pre-compiled binary "boost_1_68_0-msvc-14.0-64.exe" downloaded from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.68.0/).

Problem:
When calling `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS ...)`, FindBoost.cmake reports an error:

> CMake Error at C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1535
>   (_Boost_UPDATE_WINDOWS_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_WITH_PREBUILT_PATHS):
>   Unknown CMake command
>   "_Boost_UPDATE_WINDOWS_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_WITH_PREBUILT_PATHS".

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Strange, the function should be defined at [FindBoost.cmake:1018](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.12.4/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L1018). You may check that definition in your `FindBoost.cmake` file (referenced in the error message).

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I didn't find the definition in line 1018, nor anywhere else in FindBoost.cmake.

Comment: You may try to replace your `FindBoost.cmake` file with one from the official repo. You may even take the newest one for replace, no need to take the one corresponded to 3.12.4 version.

Comment: Did CMake deliberately not test on Windows so that users have to purchase their support?

Comment: What support you are talking about? CMake is free both on Linux and Windows. It is very possible that your CMake installation is broken somehow - the function exists in every version of `FindBoost.cmake` script near the 3.12.4.

Comment: It is obviously not true. There is no such definition in FindBoost.cmake in 3.12.4. If you don't agree, show me where it is.

Comment: CMake support is for purchase at thousands of US dollars. Do you know that? Don't tell me that you are a (free) supporter of CMake.

Comment: I meant, that looking into [FindBoost.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake) in the CMake repo, and selecting different tags (which corresponds to CMake versions), you may find that function `_Boost_UPDATE_WINDOWS_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_WITH_PREBUILT_PATHS` is defined in the script of every tag `3.12.*` (including `3.12.4`). And no, I have no relation with CMake team.